Find the Size of a File in a Portable Manner
There's no function in the Standard C Library to determine the size of a file. The POSIX Standard has stat()/fstat() which are well supported (Windows have them too, except that they're preceded with underscores), so I have used them:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define IO_CHUNK_SIZE          ((size_t)1024 * 64)

/* Reasons to not use `fseek()` and `ftell()` to compute the size of the file:
 * 
 * Subclause 7.12.9.2 of the C Standard [ISO/IEC 9899:2011] specifies the
 * following behavior when opening a binary file in binary mode:
 * 
 * >> A binary stream need not meaningfully support fseek calls with a whence 
 * >> value of SEEK_END.
 *
 * In addition, footnote 268 of subclause 7.21.3 says:
 *
 * >> Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with 
 * >> fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END) has undefined behavior for a binary stream.
 *
 * For regular files, the file position indicator returned by ftell() is useful
 * only in calls to fseek(). As such, the value returned may not be reflect the 
 * physical byte offset. */
bool io_fsize(FILE *stream, uintmax_t *size)
{
/*   Windows supports fileno(), struct stat, and fstat() as _fileno(),
 *   _fstat(), and struct _stat.
 *
 *   See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fstat-fstat32-fstat64-fstati64-fstat32i64-fstat64i32?view=msvc-170 */
#ifdef _WIN32
    #define fileno _fileno
    #ifdef _WIN64
        #define fstat  _fstat64
        #define stat   __stat64
    #else
        /* Does this suffice for a 32-bit system? */
        #define fstat  _fstat
        #define stat   _stat
    #endif                          /* _WIN64 */
#endif                              /* _WIN32 */

/* According to https://web.archive.org/web/20191012035921/http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system
 * __unix__ should suffice for IBM AIX, all distributions of BSD, and all
 * distributions of Linux, and Hewlett-Packard HP-UX. __unix suffices for Oracle
 * Solaris. Mac OSX and iOS compilers do not define the conventional __unix__,
 * __unix, or unix macros, so they're checked for separately. WIN32 is defined
 * on 64-bit systems too. */
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix) || (defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__))

#include <sys/stat.h>

    struct stat st;

    /* rewind() returns no value. */
    rewind(stream);

    if (fstat(fileno(stream), &st) == 0) {
        *size = (uintmax_t) st.st_size;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
#else
    /* Fall back to the default and read it in chunks. */
    uintmax_t rcount = 0;
    char chunk[IO_CHUNK_SIZE];

    /* rewind() returns no value. */
    rewind(stream);

    do {
        rcount = fread(chunk, 1, IO_CHUNK_SIZE, stream);

        if ((*size + rcount) < *size) {
            /* Overflow. */
            return false;
        }
        *size += rcount;
    } while (rcount == IO_CHUNK_SIZE);
    return !ferror(stream);
#endif                          /* defined(_WIN32) || defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix) || (defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)) */
#undef fstat
#undef stat
#undef fileno
}

Review Request:
Bugs, style, et cetera.

Note that the size of a file is a transient thing - by the time the information is used, it may well be out of date.

I'm not sure that we need the macro IO_CHUNK_SIZE - since it's an arbitrary size, we could simply
    char chunk[65536];

and then
        rcount = fread(chunk, 1, sizeof chunk, stream);

I've used literal 65536, as C coders are all familiar with common powers of two - I certainly find that more readable than the computation with the cast in it.

The two implementations differ in the position they leave the stream after they are called - the stat() version leaves the position indicator at start of file and the portable version at the end.  The function comment doesn't mention that it is modified at all.
I think it would be better in the first version not to call rewind().  In the second version, I would save the stream position at the start of function using ftell() and restore it with fseek() after calculating the size.  Then we'd be able to leave the stream in the state we left it (assuming we're not called in the middle of a multibyte character).

When we use fstat(), we blindly copy the st_size field into our output.  Yet that's not always valid:


For regular files, the file size in bytes.
For symbolic links, the length in bytes of the  pathname contained in the symbolic link.
For a shared memory object, the length in bytes.
For a typed memory object, the length in bytes.
For other file types, the use of this field is  unspecified.


(my emphasis)
We should probably be returning false if (for example) S_ISDIR(fd).  Consider setting errno to EISDIR in this case, too.  And handle the rest of the "other file types".


    if ((*size + rcount) < *size) {
        /* Overflow. */
        return false;
    }


Consider setting errno = EFBIG if available.

The #if test for use of fstat() could probably be simplified by testing for _POSIX_C_SOURCE, since it's a POSIX function (that might make it more inclusive, too - we'd like Hurd to use the fast path, for example).  We need to apply the same test before including <sys/stat.h>, too.

char chunk[65536]; --> char chunk[16*1024]; has the advantage of working on systems where size_t is 16-bit with only nominal performance loss.

Other way around - if 16*1024 overflows, that's a zero, but literal 65536 will always be 65536 even if that's a long.   65536u might be clearer, though.

16*1024 never overflows.  This is not a multiplication issue.  Reword: char chunk[65536]; --> better as char chunk[16384]; (or maybe 8192, 4096).   65536 > SIZE_MAX is the concern as the minimum bit size of size_t may only be 16 bits and 65536 is not a valid array size.

Oh, minimal size_t - again the multiplication obfuscated things.  Quite right - and there's probably little benefit going beyond typical storage block size around 4K or so.

"And handle the rest of the "other file types"." ==> Just fail if it is not a regular file or a symbolic link?

I also found EISNAM. What is a named type file? A pipe? In what case should I set errno to EISNAM?

You might be able to return a useful size for a shared memory mapping; for a symbolic link, probably better to follow the link - I think that's what users would expect.  For the other types: yes, fail, and possibly give some indication that it's an invalid operation for that particular descriptor.
